# Generic Netlink unicast from kernel to user fails (-111)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, netlink

(Linux 4.4)

I am trying to get a kernel module to send information to a user process over a Generic Netlink.  It seems that the message is not successfully received by the user process - the nlmsg_unicast function returns with -111.

Here is what I know:

- The kernel module successfully registers a Generic Netlink family - it prints a message in the syslog indicating the (autogenerated) family ID (which is always 26).
- The user process successfully discovers the family ID (26).
- The user process sends a sort of "I'm alive" command to the kernel module, which successfully logs the (auto-selected) port ID of the user process - I know from messages printed by both the user process and the kernel module that the correct portID is resolved.
- Subsequently, the kernel, upon an event, tries to send a message to the resolved portID over the Generic Netlink family that had been set up.
- The user process never receives the message (it never enters the callback function; in fact, I don't think mnl_socket_recvfrom ever returns).  In the kernel module, the nlmsg_unicast function returns with -111.

I am using libmnl in the user process (as you might have guessed from my allusion to mnl_socket_recvfrom).

uname -a
 Linux yaron-VirtualBox 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Here is, essentially, my send code in the kernel:

```
    struct sk_buff *msg;
    struct sock *socket;
    struct netlink_kernel_cfg nlCfg = {
        .groups = 1,
        .flags = 0,
        .input = NULL,
        .cb_mutex = NULL,
        .bind = NULL,
        .unbind = NULL,
        .compare = NULL,
    };
    void *msg_head;
    int retval;
    struct net init_net;

            /* Open a socket */
            socket = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, NETLINK_GENERIC, &nlCfg);
            if (socket == NULL) goto CmdFail;

            /* Allocate space */
            msg = genlmsg_new(NLMSG_GOODSIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
            if (msg == NULL) goto CmdFail;

            /* Generate message header
             * arguments of genlmsg_put: 
             *    struct sk_buff *, 
             *    int portID,  <-- this is sender portID
             *    int netlinkSeqNum,
             *    struct genl_family *, 
             *    int flags, 
             *    u8 command_idx         */
            msg_head = genlmsg_put(msg, 0, ++netlinkSeqNum, &genlFamily, 0, MYFAMILY_CMD_MYMSG);
            if (msg_head == NULL) goto CmdFail;

            /* Add a MYFAMILY_ATTR_MYCMD attribute (command to be sent) */
            retval = nla_put_string(msg, MYFAMILY_ATTR_MYMSG, "Temporary message");
            if (retval != 0) goto CmdFail;

            /* Finalize the message */
            genlmsg_end(msg, msg_head);  /* void inline function - no return value */

            /* Send the message */
            retval = nlmsg_unicast(socket, msg, userNetlinkPortID);
            printk("nlmsg_unicast returned %d\n", retval);
            if (retval != 0) goto CmdFail;

            netlink_kernel_release(socket);

            return;


CmdFail:
    printk(KERN_ALERT "*** Failed to send command !\n");
    netlink_kernel_release(socket);
    return;
```

Here is, essentially, my receive code in the user process:

```
char bufferHdr[getpagesize()];
struct nlmsghdr *nlHeader;
struct genlmsghdr *nlHeaderExtraHdr;
int numBytes, seq, ret_val;

// Set up the header.
// Function mnl_nlmsg_put_header will zero out a length of bufferHdr sufficient to hold a Netlink header,
// and initialize the nlmsg_len field in that space to the size of a header.
// It returns a pointer to bufferHdr.
if ( (nlHeader = mnl_nlmsg_put_header(bufferHdr)) != (struct nlmsghdr *) bufferHdr ) {
    perror("mnl_nlmsg_put_header failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
nlHeader->nlmsg_type = genetlinkFamilyID;

// Function mnl_nlmsg_put_extra_header extends the header, to allow for these extra fields.
if ( (nlHeaderExtraHdr = (struct genlmsghdr *) mnl_nlmsg_put_extra_header(nlHeader, sizeof(struct genlmsghdr))) != (struct genlmsghdr *) (bufferHdr + sizeof(struct nlmsghdr)) ) {
    perror("mnl_nlmsg_put_extra_header failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// No command to set

// No attributes to set

// Wait for a message, and process it
while (1) {
    numBytes = mnl_socket_recvfrom(nlSocket, bufferHdr, sizeof(bufferHdr));
    if (numBytes == -1) {
        perror("mnl_socket_recvfrom returned error");
        break;
    }
    // Callback run queue handler - use it to call getMsgCallback
    std::cout << "received a msg, handling it" << std::endl;
    ret_val = mnl_cb_run(bufferHdr, numBytes, seq, portid, getMsgCallback, NULL);
    if (ret_val == -1) {
        //perror("mnl_cb_run failed");
        break;
    } else if (ret_val == 0)
        break;

}

return ret_val;
```

---

**ADDENDUM:**
Having scoured through the kernel source code some more (on elixir.free-electrons.com), I'm guessing that my message never even gets to the user process; suggestions for debugging would be appreciated.

Here is what I'm seeing: `nlmsg_unicast` calls `netlink_unicast`, which in turn calls `netlink_getsockbyportid`, which looks like this:

```
static struct sock *netlink_getsockbyportid(struct sock *ssk, u32 portid)
{
    struct sock *sock;
    struct netlink_sock *nlk;

    sock = netlink_lookup(sock_net(ssk), ssk->sk_protocol, portid);
    if (!sock)
        return ERR_PTR(-ECONNREFUSED);

    /* Don't bother queuing skb if kernel socket has no input function */
    nlk = nlk_sk(sock);
    if (sock->sk_state == NETLINK_CONNECTED &&
        nlk->dst_portid != nlk_sk(ssk)->portid) {
        sock_put(sock);
        return ERR_PTR(-ECONNREFUSED);
    }
    return sock;
}
```

I'm guessing one of the two conditions here for punting and returning -ECONNREFUSED is triggered.

Any suggestions for how I can debug whether either of these conditions is true?  It doesn't look like I can call `netlink_lookup` or `nlk_sk` directly from my module code - I guess the symbols are not exposed - nor their subfunctions - a whole lot of symbols are buried in af_netlink.h and af_netlink.c, and I guess the symbols are not available when building your external module, at least the normal way.  (It doesn't look like af_netlink.h is available as part of the distro.)